# Interpretation of survival risk predictions generated from R's predictSurvProb

Tags: r, probability, self-study, survival, cox-model

I am starting to learn R and its power for giving survival predictions.

#### Abstract

I use the `predictSurvProb` function from the `pec` package to get predicted survival risks. My data has 5000 rows wherein each thousand falls into a certain `time` category. These `time` categories are separated by two-year intervals; thus for time periods one to five, these have 1000 records that fall within these ranges.

My data has 47 variables: the time and event; 20 numeric, 10 binary and 15 nominal predictive variables.

My steps to generate the risks are as follows:

1. Fit a Cox model, `xn`s are the rest of the predictive variables.

   ```
   coxmodel <- cph(Surv(time,event)~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5, 
       data=myData, surv=TRUE, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
   ```
2. Declare time periods.

   ```
   myTime <- c(24,48,72,96,120) # months
   periods <- quantile(myTime, conf.int=TRUE)
   ```
3. Get the prediction risks!

   ```
   survRiskPreds <- predictSurvProb(coxmodel, newdata=myData, times=periods)
   round(preds, digits=6)
   ```

#### Problem

(Note that these below are example results but nonetheless represent the phenomena that I'm facing.)

Since I have five different time periods, I expect each of the 1000 records to have optimistic results in their own time period for example:

```
                                  24      48      72      96     120 
Record survives for 30 months : 0.96251 0.81881 0.65141 0.46836 0.11000
Record survives for 60 months : ?       0.96251 0.81881 0.65141 0.46836
Record survives for 90 months : ?       ?       0.96251 0.81881 0.65141
Record survives for 100 months: ?       ?       ?       0.96251 0.81881 
Record survives for 150 months: ?       ?       ?       ?       0.96251
```

But in reality the results have the pattern for all records no matter what their `time` value is:

```
                                  24      48      72      96     120 
Record survives for 30 months : 0.96251 0.81881 0.65141 0.46836 0.11000
Record survives for 60 months : 0.98111 0.83809 0.71174 0.60173 0.21272
Record survives for 90 months : 0.95411 0.82209 0.69974 0.51936 0.20272
Record survives for 100 months: 0.99911 0.88909 0.60074 0.57736 0.21272
Record survives for 150 months: 0.98801 0.78109 0.68211 0.51436 0.33272
```

#### Sample data and code

I made a [dummy dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oweuy6lyocyrxr1/dummy.csv) that more or less represents the one I currently have.

Below is the script I use to manipulate the data. I included all predictive variables in the Cox model.

```
library(survival)
library(pec) 
library(rms)

theData <- read.csv("dummy.csv",
 colClasses=c(
   "female"="factor",
   "bin1"="factor",
   "bin2"="factor",
   "marital"="factor",
   "yrDiagnosis"="factor",
   "response1"="factor",
   "response2"="factor",
   "response3"="factor",
   "country"="factor",
   "race"="factor"))
attach(theData)

# removed one predictive variable (yrDiagnosis) because it caused an error
coxmodel <- cph(Surv(time,event)~age+num1+num2+num3+num4+
  num5+female+bin1+bin2+marital+response1+
  response2+response3+response4+response5+response6+country+race  
  , data=myData, surv=TRUE, x=TRUE, y=TRUE) 
coxmodel 

myTime <- c(24,48,72,96,120)
periods <- quantile(myTime, conf.int=TRUE)
periods

preds <- predictSurvProb(coxmodel, newdata=theData, times=periods)
round(preds[1:5,], digits=6)       # survival within 24 months
round(preds[1000:1005,], digits=6) # survival within 48 months
round(preds[2000:2005,], digits=6) # survival within 72 months
round(preds[3000:3005,], digits=6) # survival within 96 months
round(preds[4000:4005,], digits=6) # survival within 120 months
```

---

Am I doing something wrong ie. wrong format in the `predictSurvProb` steps?

I am not familiar with other R packages but I would appreciate if anyone guides me get to my desired result.

Comment: Since time is not a predictor but the response of your model, the predictions are independent of newely observed times.

Comment: @MichaelMayer, thank you and I updated the question with your suggestion!

Comment: You shouldn't include the response variable as predictor. Sorry for that. I was trying to show you the logical mistake in your OP. It is like predicting income based on income...

Comment: @MichaelMayer, it's okay, I really appreciate the attention though! Plus I learned that that is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through the `predictSurvProb`-function you use the model to predict the survival probability (probability to be alive at that specific timepoint) for each individual at each timepoint you enter in the `times`-argument. Theoretically, if the model predictions would perfectly correspond to the observed situation, the predicted survival probability would be 0 for an observation who died before the particular timepoint for which you want the prediction. However, in reality this is never the case and the model provides you with a predicted probability between 0 and 1 which is most likely for a given combination of covariables. Thus, for individual observations, the predicted suvival probability for 1 person will never be equal to the observed probability as the latter is either 0 (death) or 1 (alive). However, depending on how well your model performs, the predicted probabilities should correspond to the observed probabilities on a group/population level. (E.g. for observations with a certain combination of predictor values, on average, the predicted survival probabilities should correspond to the observed survival (KM-estimates)).

This is also why you will have to validate your model by assessing the predictive performance. For discrimination see the functions `cindex`-from the `pec`-package or `validate`from the `rms`-package. To evaluate the calibration it is advisable to make a calibration plot. Futhermore, to assess the clinical benefit of a model you could consider decision curve analyses (see paper by [Vickers](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17099194) and this overview [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20010215)). For further reading also see the books by [Harrell](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-95232-1) and [Steyerberg](http://www.clinicalpredictionmodels.org/).

P.S. There is no need to take quantiles for your timepoints, just enter `c(24,48,72,96,120)` in the `times`-argument when calling `predictSurvProb`.